# Trouble running test code 'paraboloid_min.py'

Tags: python, openmdao

I am trying to include openMDAO in my teaching hence downloaded the zip file and installed as indicated.

However, when I try to run the test code `paraboloid_min.py` shown in the Getting started, I get the error msg

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matmul'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's either you don't have numpy installed or you have an old version of numpy.

- Install numpy `pip install numpy`
- Try to upgrade your numpy `pip install --upgrade numpy`

Comment: Worked !!  I got the expected answer specified in the Getting Started page. Thanks a Ton.